# Start Function When in View

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this script that "animates" numbers creating a counting effect. I like it for what I'm doing, however, I only want it to run when the element is in view. Otherwise it's already done counting by the time you scroll down to it.

It's set up like this:

`<span id="num" class="num" data-val="80">00</span>`

```
let hasBeenAnimated = false;
let valueDisplays = document.querySelectorAll(".num");
let interval = 400;

$.fn.isInViewport = function () {
    let elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    let elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
    let viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    let viewportBottom = viewportTop + window.innerHeight;

    return elementBottom > viewportTop && viewportTop < viewportBottom;
};

function count() {
    valueDisplays.forEach((valueDisplay) => {
        let startValue = 0;
        let endValue = parseInt(valueDisplay.getAttribute("data-val"));
        let duration = Math.floor(interval / endValue);
        let counter = setInterval(function () {
            startValue += 1;
            valueDisplay.textContent = startValue;
            if (startValue == endValue) {
                clearInterval(counter);
            }
        }, duration);
    });
};

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('.num').isInViewport() && !hasBeenAnimated) {
        hasBeenAnimated = true;
        count();
    }
});
```

I was thinking this would only run the function when it's in view, but it still loads when the page is loaded. Am wondering what's wrong?

Comment: Did you debug `elementBottom > viewportTop && viewportTop < viewportBottom`?  elbottom will always be > viewtop and viewtop will (by definition) always be < viewBottom.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in `$.fn.isInViewport`

```
elementBottom > viewportTop && viewportTop < viewportBottom
```

as viewportTop is 0 initially, elementBottom will always be > viewportTop

and
as viewportBottom = viewportTop + innerHeight, `viewportTop < viewportBottom` will always be true.

Change to

```
return elementTop > viewportTop && elementBottom < viewportBottom;
```

Updated snippet

```js
let hasBeenAnimated = false;
let valueDisplays = document.querySelectorAll(".num");
let interval = 4000;

$.fn.isInViewport = function () {
    let elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    let elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
    let viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    let viewportBottom = viewportTop + window.innerHeight;
    
    //console.log(elementBottom, viewportTop, viewportTop, viewportBottom, elementTop > viewportTop && elementBottom < viewportBottom)

    return elementTop > viewportTop && elementBottom < viewportBottom;
};

function count() {
    console.log("count")
    valueDisplays.forEach((valueDisplay) => {
        let startValue = 0;
        let endValue = parseInt(valueDisplay.getAttribute("data-val"));
        let duration = Math.floor(interval / endValue);
        let counter = setInterval(function () {
            startValue += 1;
            valueDisplay.textContent = startValue;
            if (startValue == endValue) {
                clearInterval(counter);
            }
        }, duration);
    });
};

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('.num').isInViewport() && !hasBeenAnimated) {
        console.log("start")
        hasBeenAnimated = true;
        count();
    }
});
console.log($('.num').isInViewport())
```

```css
#spacer { height:1200px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='spacer'>

</div>
<div class='num' data-val='100'>

</div>
```